# Repeat regex n time error in python3

Tags: python-3.x

In my code I got answer `[('hathatat', 'hat')]` but I want `[('hathatat')]`. And please some one tell how to repeater any whole regex for n time.

```
import re
x='hathatatlatrat'
y = re.findall("((hat){2}at)",x)
print(y)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```
y = re.findall('((?:hat){2}at)', x)
```

`hat` will not be captured this way.